# How to find all the queries in a single function has been executed?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created form which contains lots of fields . I am storing the fields in various tables . I have written insert queries for all the tables separately in a single function . I should make sure that all the queries are executed . In case the queries are partially executed i should delete all the values inserted through partial execution . How do i do this ?

Comment: Look into transactions, that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need [MySql transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) (not clear what you use, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php))

```
/* START TRANSACTION; */

try {
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // INSERT / UPDATE
    /* COMMIT; */
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
  /* ROLLBACK; */
}
```